# Android library with dependency not resolving properly

Tags: android, gradle, android-library

So I have an Android library project, `SimpleWidget`.  I publish it to jcenter.

I can make a new project and add `implementation 'my.project:simplewidget:1.2.3'` and everything works as expected, I can use `SimpleWidget` instances and their public APIs.

Now I make another Android library project, `ComplexWidget`.  `ComplexWidget` is a subclass of `SimpleWidget`.  I add `implementation 'my.project:simplewidget:1.2.3'` to the build.gradle and everything resolves, and in fact I can even get away without lint yelling for something super basic like `ComplexWidget complexWidget = new ComplexWidget()`.

However, the project will not compile.  Any `ComplexWidget` method that has a return or parameter type of `SimpleWidget` (e.g., many of the inherited methods, or an interface that accepts `SimpleWidget` arguments, or a Factory that returns `SimpleWidget` instances) will not compile and Android Studio complains that "Cannot access my.project.SimpleWidget".

Not sure if I should even mention it for fear of muddying the waters, but if I command click `SimpleWidget` in, for example, `public class ComplexWidget extends SimpleWidget`, I get a warning at the top of the file that "Library source does not match the byetcode for the class SimpleWidget".

Any ideas?

TYIA

Comment: try to use `api` instead of `implementation`

Answer (score 0):

use `api 'my.project:SimpleWidget:1.2.3'` instead